# Changing height of Header in React Native Stack Navigator doesn't work

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am trying to change the style of the header of a Stack Navigator and everything works fine except the height property. I am also nesting the Stack Navigator inside a Drawer Navigator. When I change the height of its header, everything works fine.

I tested it on my AVD and iPhone with Expo Go and it doesn't work. In the web browser, it works fine.

**Both headers should have the same height (150px)**
[image]

Drawer:

```
import React from "react";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";

import HomeStack from "./HomeStack";
import AboutStack from "./AboutStack";

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function Drawer() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <DrawerNavigator.Navigator
                screenOptions={{
                    headerShown: true,
                    headerStyle: {
                        height: 150,
                    },
                }}
            >
                <DrawerNavigator.Screen name="HomeStack" component={HomeStack} />
                <DrawerNavigator.Screen name="AboutStack" component={AboutStack} />
            </DrawerNavigator.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

AboutStack:

```
import React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import About from "../screens/About";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function AboutStack() {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                headerStyle: {
                    height: 150,
                    backgroundColor: "#111",
                },
                headerTintColor: "#fff",
            }}
        >
            <Stack.Screen
                name="About"
                component={About}
                options={{
                    title: "About GameZone",
                }}
            />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}
```

Comment: thank you, this help me solve my problem about style of header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue here with not being able to set the header height and having some additional padding in the header. I found out in the end that it was because I was using the native stack navigator.

In the docs they actually mention that using @react-navigation/native-stack navigator over @react-navigation/stack offers native performance but is less customisable. In my case I found once I reverted to the non native navigator I was able to change header height and customise more etc. I wasted a good few hours on this so hope this can save someone the pain.... read the docs lol

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator

Answer (score 0):

You can use this documentation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/ .Also you can try

```
headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          },
```

for that purpose .

Comment: what a terrible answer to a question.